# How to store a file on server?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, webserver, private-key

I have access to a SOAP web service, and I have a file for the Android app I am making that needs to be stored on my server. I do not need to upload a new one for every user of the app or anything; there is just the one file and it needs to be uploaded just once, but will need to be read by each user's app.

How do I add it to the web service? Do I need to contact the person who wrote the web service and have them add it in, or am I able to upload it on my own? If applicable, Android/Java code or links to tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is quite loaded. You ask three different questions

1) How do I upload something to the server? Should I ask developer to modify it for that?

The answer is: The server should support accepting and storing a thing which you try to upload. If it's capable of that now, you don't need to server developer to add anything. If the server isn't capable, you will need to ask to provide some UI, API for this

2) How should I store securely P12 on my server

Do you want to protect this file against somebody who can legally access server or somebody who can hack the server?

P12 file is encrypted. So, it's not a matter of securely storing file itself, but rather who knows the password. So, the main question is should you upload the password, should only user know the password, should you upload hash of the password? It's hard to answer it without better understanding of what you are trying to do.

3) How to upload something to the server from Android?

I think  you may be interested to look at kSOAP (http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). It allows you to work with the server.

However, since you need it once, may be just FTP upload of the file will be ok for you?

I would recommend to edit your questions and describe what is the overall problem you are trying to solve.